# how to print a increment value using bash

Tags: bash

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
   ADDRESS=$(head -$i "$project_name/address" | tail -1 | cut -f2)
   sed -i.old "20s/.\{60\}/&${ADDRESS}/" "Desktop/lscript.ld"
done
```

I am using this code according to this:

```
if [[ i = 1 ]]
then
    ADDRESS=$(head -1 "$project_name/address" | tail -1 | cut -f2)
fi
```

will be executed but i want the `head` value to be incremented by 1 each time.

When `i=1` i want `head -2` to be executed, for `i=2` i want `head -3`. How can i do this using Bash?

Comment: Instead of using `seq`, you can do `for i in {1..100}` or `for ((i = 1; i <= 100; i++))`. Using `head`/`tail` to step through a file line-by-line can be very slow. You can use `while read line; do ...; done < filename` instead. `sed -i.old` is going to write the backup file 100 times, each different, so there's hardly any point in preserving it (in other words, omit the extension). Also, line 20 is going to be changed each time so only the last change is going to be kept.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
   ADDRESS=$(head -n $((i + 1)) "$project_name/address" | tail -1 | cut -f2)
   sed -i.old "20s/.\{60\}/&${ADDRESS}/" "Desktop/lscript.ld"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do math using `(())`

```
$((i + 1))
```

So particularly

```
ADDRESS=$(head -$((i + 1)) "$project_name/address" | tail -1 | cut -f2)
```

This will not alter the current value of `i` (which could be achieved by `$((i++))`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm chiming in with what Dennis Williamson wrote in his comment, but even though the body of the code does nothing much useful, I'd like to show a different, more efficient way.  You are already familiar with all the features of `sed` you need to make the ADDRESS assignment much cleaner:

```
ADDRESS=$(sed -n "$i"'s/.*\t\([^\t]*\)\t.*/\1/p' "$project_name/address")
```

You could also drive the loop with `nl` to get the line numbers:

```
head -n 100 "$project_name/address" |
cut -f2 |
nl |
while read i address; do
    ... do something with $i and $address ...
done
```